# TypeError [Discord bot]

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So i have been playing around with a bot a bot recently, but theres just one commands that doesnt want to do as i will when the command is used it just gives me this in the CMD:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extracustomdesc')
at allotherembeds_eachcategory (C:\Users\emilf\OneDrive\Skrivebord\Xzito\Xzito\commands\ Info\help.js:521:97)
at Object.run (C:\Users\emilf\OneDrive\Skrivebord\Xzito\Xzito\commands\ Info\help.js:302:35)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

So far i havent tried anything, cause im really blanc, i think the errors could be in this:

```
      var embed5 = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`[\`${client.commands.filter((cmd) => cmd.category === "⚜️ Custom Queue(s)").first().extracustomdesc.length}\`] ⚜️ Custom Queue(s) Commands ⚜️ | ${settings.CUSTOMQUEUE ? "<a:yes:833101995723194437> ENABLED" : "<:no:833101993668771842> DISABLED"}`)
        .setDescription(`> *${client.commands.filter((cmd) => cmd.category === "⚜️ Custom Queue(s)").first().extracustomdesc.split(",").map(i => i?.trim()).join("︲")}*`)
        .addField("\u200b", "\u200b")
        .addField("<a:yes:833101995723194437>  **Usage**", "> "+client.commands.filter((cmd) => cmd.category === "⚜️ Custom Queue(s)").first().usage)
      if(!filterdisabled || settings.CUSTOMQUEUE || settings.showdisabled) embeds.push(embed5)
```

Or this

```
      var embed13 = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`[\`${client.commands.filter((cmd) => cmd.category === " Voice").first().extracustomdesc.length}\`]  Voice Commands  | ${settings.VOICE ? "<a:yes:833101995723194437> ENABLED" : "<:no:833101993668771842> DISABLED"}`)
        .setDescription(`> *${client.commands.filter((cmd) => cmd.category === " Voice").first().extracustomdesc.split(",").map(i => i?.trim()).join("︲")}*`)
        .addField("\u200b", "\u200b")
        .addField("<a:yes:833101995723194437>  **Usage**", "> "+client.commands.filter((cmd) => cmd.category === " Voice").first().usage)
      if(!filterdisabled || settings.VOICE || settings.showdisabled) embeds.push(embed13)
```

Line 520 to 525

```
          var embed13 = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`[\`${client.commands.filter((cmd) => cmd.category === " Voice").first().extracustomdesc.length}\`]  Voice Commands  | ${settings.VOICE ? "<a:yes:833101995723194437> ENABLED" : "<:no:833101993668771842> DISABLED"}`)
            .setDescription(`> *${client.commands.filter((cmd) => cmd.category === " Voice").first().extracustomdesc.split(",").map(i => i?.trim()).join("︲")}*`)
            .addField("\u200b", "\u200b")
            .addField("<a:yes:833101995723194437>  **Usage**", "> "+client.commands.filter((cmd) => cmd.category === " Voice").first().usage)
          if(!filterdisabled || settings.VOICE || settings.showdisabled) embeds.push(embed13)
    enter code here
```

Comment: No commands match your filter.

Comment: The error shows that the problem came from `help.js` file, at line 521. Can you show me the code on that line?

Comment: I have just edited the post to show line 520 to 525